# remove whitespace from column names after model.matrix

Tags: r, whitespace, model.matrix

I am writing you because I need to remove whitespaces in the middle of column names of a matrix. I am working in R.

In my code I have just run a model.matrix command. It adds a column for each factor, thus, if there were some whitespaces in the factor name, it is moved in the column name.

I would like to remove them.

Here below an example

```
Intercept   Region_Factor 1 A   Region_Factor 2 A    Region_Factor 3 A     VarA 10    
    1               1                  0                    0               1  
    1               0                  1                    0               0.52
 .......
```

I would like to get the column names as follow:

```
Intercept   Region_Factor_1_A    Region_Factor_2_A    Region_Factor_3_A    VarA_10
    1               1                   0                    0               1  
    1               0                   1                    0               0.52
 .......
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be to use `gsub` to match spaces in the column names and replace with `_`

```
colnames(df1) <- gsub(" ", '_', colnames(df1))
```

If there is only a single instance of space to be replaced, use `sub`

```
colnames(df1) <- sub(" ", '_', colnames(df1))
```

Or another option is `chartr`

```
colnames(df1) <- chartr( ' ', '_', colnames(df1))
```

---

Or another option is `rename_all` with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
   rename_all(~ str_replace(., ' ', '_'))
```

NOTE: The `gsub` was first answered here.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the column names with `colnames`, replace the spaces with `gsub`and put it back as column names, which is written as:

`colnames(matrix)=gsub(" ", "_", colnames(matrix), fixed = TRUE)`